# Custom health endpoints with child services status

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

- Using spring boot and actuator v1.5.13 I'm trying to achieve the following :

when I access : `myapp.site/actuator/health`, I want it to show only the default status

```
{ status : "UP" }
```

and when I access : `myapp.site/actuator/connectivity`, I want it to show the default status but also get child microservices status':

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "details": {
      "service-A": { "status": "UP" },
      "service-B": { "status": "DOWN" }
   }
}
```

- Currently I'm able to get this result (which is not satisfying for me):

When I acces `myapp.site/health`, and not `\actuator\health` for some reason, I get :

```
{
  "status": "DOWN",
  "mainService" { "status": "UP" },
  "serviceA": { "status": "UP" },
  "serviceB": { "status": "DOWN" }
}
```

I get that using the following configuration :

```
@Configuration
public class HealthConf {

    @Bean("mainService")
    HealthIndicator mainServiceHealthIndicator(){
        return () -> Health.up().build();
    }

    @Bean("serviceA")
    HealthIndicator serviceAHealthIndicator(){
        return new ServiceHealthIndicator(serviceAURL);
    }

    @Bean("serviceB")
    HealthIndicator serviceBHealthIndicator(){
        return new ServiceHealthIndicator(serviceBURL);
    }
}

public class ServiceHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        try {
            JsonNode resp = restTemplate.getForObject(serviceUrl + "/health", JsonNode.class);
            if (resp.get("status").asText().equalsIgnoreCase("UP")) {
                return Health.up().build();
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // return Health.down(e).build();
        }
        return Health.down().build();
    }

}

// app.properties 
############## ACTUATOR CONFIG ################
management.security.enabled=false
endpoints.enabled=false
endpoints.health.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health
endpoints.jmx.enabled=false
management.health.defaults.enabled=false
management.endpoint.health.group.services.include=serviceA,serviceB
```

- So as you noticed, I have the following differences that I'm trying to overcome:

1. the services are on the same level as their parent.
2. the parent service showing "down" if one of it's child services (a or b) is down. I added the node "mainService" to overcome this, but I think it's ugly as I want it to show "UP" all the times.
3. I don't have 2 separate urls for checking health : /health and /connectivity
4. for some reason my urls are accessible directly from base path and not from /actuator/...

Comment: any ideas :'( ?